# In a list of lists how to get all the items except the last one for each list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

So I have this list of lists. Each nested list has `n+1` element where the first element are floats and the last one is an integer. I need to get , for each nested list, all the floats (so n elements out of `n+1`). Which is the best way to achieve that?

For example:

```
x = [[0.1, 0.2, 1], [0.4, 0.05, 16], [0.3, 0.3, 5]]
output = [[0.1, 0.2], [0.4, 0.05], [0.3, 0.3]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the shortest and easiest way:

```
output = [l[:-1] for l in x]
```

It is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) .

Answer (score 3):

If you are *certain* the `int` will always be last, slicing is an option whereby you trim off the last element from every sub-list `sub` in `x` with `sub[:-1]` (`[:-1]` means grab all except the last element):

```
out = [sub[:-1] for sub in x] # or sub[:2] if sub is always 3 elements long
print(out)
[[0.1, 0.2], [0.4, 0.05], [0.3, 0.3]]
```

Alternatively, you can do this by iterating through the elements of `x`, iterating through each sub-element and evaluating if it is an instance of a `float`, i.e:

```
out = [[i for i in sub if isinstance(i, float)] for sub in x]
```

This filters out any element the list `sub` which is a sub-list in `x` that isn't an instance of the `float` type. This operates *irregardless of positioning* so you could use it if the position of the `int` isn't always last:

```
print(out)
[[0.1, 0.2], [0.4, 0.05], [0.3, 0.3]]
```

Finally, for an *in-place* approach, `for` looping and `pop`ing is a viable option:

```
for s in x: _ = s.pop()
```

Now `x` is mutated to:

```
print(x)
[[0.1, 0.2], [0.4, 0.05], [0.3, 0.3]]
```

Comment: If someone believes this answer is not useful I'd be more than willing to edit it and fix it. :-)